# how to get cell fill colors

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am trying to get the string value of a cell from a workbook, using xlsx package.  Using the `getFillBackgroundColorColor(`) and `getFillForegroundColorColor()` methods I get back Java-Object gibberish, like `"Java-Object{org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPalette$CustomColor@7ec7ffd3}"`.  Does 7ec7ffd3 hide the hex values of the color? Any ideas how I extract the color name?  Thanks.

Comment: Colors are usually defined as 6 hex numbers. So I don't think the `7ec7ffd3` is what you are looking for. What does `getCellStyle()` give you?

Comment: `getCellStyle()` gets back a Java cell style Object that I can't parse:  `"Java-Object{org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle@f8ba60aa}"`.   Also, `7ec7ffd3`  is 8 hex digits, not 6.  makes me think it's just a pointer to the Java object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those numbers are just an object identifier. What you need is the `getRgb` method.

**Added steps** This is how I set things up before steps in the original answer:

```
wb = loadWorkbook(file="Test.xlsx")
SheetList = getSheets(wb)
Rows = getRows(SheetList[[1]])
Cells = getCells(Rows)
```

**Original Answer**

```
Style = getCellStyle(Cells[["2.1"]])
Style$getFillForegroundColorColor()$getRgb()
[1] 00 b0 50
as.character(Style$getFillForegroundColorColor()$getRgb())
[1] "00" "b0" "50"
```

Comment: your solution produces this error for me: `Error in Style$getFillForegroundColorColor()$getRGB : 
  no field, method or inner class called 'getRGB'`

Comment: Adding some previous steps to the answer. Tested again. Still working for me. Using `xlsx_0.5.7`   and   `xlsxjars_0.6.1` with `R version 3.4.1`

Comment: Did you include the () after getRGB?

Comment: I rechecked and the command fails on some cells.  I am not quite sure why.  Most of the time is works great.  Thanks for taking the time to answer!